# Redirects in Django

Tags: python, django, module, connection, access-denied

I'm working on the Helpdesk module from Django.

I want people who try to access `192.168.x.xxx:8000/helpdesk/` are redirected to the login page: `192.168.x.xxx:8000/helpdesk/login/?next=/helpdesk/`

I also want people who try to access an nonexistant page to be redirected to:

- the homepage if connected, or
- the login page if not connected.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [ask] a good question, and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find an answer for the first part of my question. I just used the import login_required. Just before the function homepage in /helpdesk/public.py and the function index in /helpdesk/kb.py, I put @login_required(login_url='/helpdesk/login/?next=/helpdesk/) and it worked !

Now I try to find the answer of the second part (redirection).